# Powershell re-use Get-Help -showwindow

Tags: powershell, window, components, helper

Powershell has a "Text display window" 
that you can invoke passing the -showwindow parameter
to the Get-Help commandlet... you can test it with:

> Get-help about_powershell.exe -ShowWindow

I find this window very useful
as it already have find and text scale funcionality,
and I want to use it to display some of my text information,
from inside a Powershell script...

?does anyone know how to instantiate that window in Powershell
and pass a text for display??

Comment: i don't know of any other way to use that window. _however_, you may be able to get what you need via the `Out-GridView` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks Lee... I use Out-GridView for other purpouses... I can also create a GUI component to do the same.. but the intent here is to use a functionality that is already there... and you will get it in any other computer without installing external libraries or modules...

Comment: from what i can tell from reading the PoSh github site, that window is built into the `Get-Help` code ... and requires WPF. that last is not [yet] supported anywhere other than windows. the githubs issue i skimmed seem to imply that the whole thing will go away and be replaced with something that displays markdown - "some day". [*grin*]